# Why is $PATH in remote deployment path different from $PATH in remote system?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, anaconda

I'm currently working on Pycharm with remote python Interpreter(miniconda3/bin/python).

So when I type `echo $PATH` in remote server, it prints 
`/home/woosung/bin:/home/woosung/.local/bin:/home/woosung/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

I created project in Pycharm and set remote python Interpreter as miniconda3 python, it works well when I just run some `*.py` files.

But when I typed some `os.system()` lines, weird things happened.
For instance, in `test.py` from Pycharm project

```
import os

os.system('echo $PATH')
os.system('python --version')
```

Output is

```
ssh://woosung@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/home/woosung/miniconda3/bin/python -u /tmp/pycharm_project_203/test.py
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Python 2.7.12

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried same command in remote server,

```
woosung@test-pc:~$ echo $PATH
/home/woosung/bin:/home/woosung/.local/bin:/home/woosung/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
woosung@test-pc:~$ python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

PATH and the version of python are totally different! How can I fix this?

I've already tried add `os.system('export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/bin"')` to `test.py`. But it still gives same `$PATH`.(`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`)

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment of @Dietrich Epp, I successfully add interpreter path to the shell $PATH.
(`os.environ["PATH"] += ":/home/woosung/miniconda3/bin"`)
But I stuck the more basic problem. When I add the path and execute command the some `*.py` file including `import` library which is only in miniconda3, the shell gives `ImportError`.

For instance, in `test.py`

```
import matplotlib

os.environ["PATH"] += ":/home/woosung/miniconda3/bin"
os.system("python import_test.py")
```

and `import_test.py`

```
import matplotlib
```

And when I run `test.py`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Looks like the shell doesn't understand how to utilize modified $PATH.

Comment: `os.system('export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/bin"')` doesn't actually do anything at all, because it runs a shell process, the shell sets its own environment variable, and when the shell exits the path of the parent process is unmodified. If you want to adjust the environment in a Python script, see `os.environ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
It is not direct but quite simple.
I changed `os.system("python import_test.py")` to `os.system(sys.executable + ' import_test.py')`.

This makes the shell uses the Pycharm remote interpreter(miniconda3), not original.